# What is the best way to get response time in OSB

Tags: web-services, servicebus, oracle12c, osb, response-time

I am doing it like this:
Inside OSB pipeline's message flow, at the beginning of request, assign the current time to a variable. Then in the response, use the current time of the response subtract the variable to calculate the response time. Then I have a reporting action to reporting this number.

I know OSB has a build in monitoring tool, it can display the response time for proxy server, pipeline and business server. As you can see my solution only include the time from the beginning of the pipeline + business server, but not including the time of the request and response message going through the proxy server. Besides that calculating it this way also feels like a non-standard approach.

OSB provided a JMX API which can get these build in monitoring data. But this would make our project more complicated.

If we want to use the OSB reporting action to report the response time. Is there a best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just switch Weblogic to use extended log format, and tell it to add `time-taken` to the list of tokens it logs on each response.

http://middlewaretechnologies.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/configure-extended-logging-in-http.html

or if you want to read the official docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13701/web_server.htm#CNFGD207